# How to say sir/ma'am when you don't know the name of the person

Tags: politeness

When you don't someone's name, how do you call his attention? That is, when you would say "Sir, could you maybe ..." or "ma'am, you dropped something ..."

Answer (score 5):

If you are working and they are a customer, then お[客]{きゃく}さま is a pretty normal way to refer to  someone.

Also in many contexts,

お[兄]{にい}さん

お[姉]{ねえ}さん

お[父]{とう}さん

お[母]{かあ}さん

おじさん

おばさん

おじいさん

おばあさん

function as ways to address people when you don't know depending on the person's age.

But perhaps the most common way to get someone's attention is すみません spoken in their direction.

Comment: おじさん

おばさん

おじいさん

おばあさん aren't these pretty informal? I don't imagine calling any older unknown lady  おばあさん, unless she's my grandmother.

Comment: No, they're pretty normal but one needs to be careful about the age.

Comment: お父さん, お母さん are used more than おじさん etc.